# Закругление углов внутри блока

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть код типа такого

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>тест</title>
    <style>
      #lkmenu {
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        border-radius: 30px;
      }

      .lbltab {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }

      .lbltab:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="lkmenu">
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 1</label>
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 2</label>
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 3</label>
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 4</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Как сделать, чтобы фон первого и последнего элементов, когда к ним подводят мышку, не вылезал за границу блока `lkmenu`? Писать для первого и последнего пунктов меню отдельные классы, в которых закруглять их углы на тот же радиус, или есть более разумное и общепринятое решение?

Comment: `#lkmenu {overflow: hidden;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавил `overflow: hidden;` в селектор `#lkmenu`, работает.

> ## lkmenu {overflow: hidden;} – Elena

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>тест</title>
    <style>
      #lkmenu {
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        border-radius: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .lbltab {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }

      .lbltab:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="lkmenu">
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 1</label>
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 2</label>
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 3</label>
      <label class="lbltab">Пункт 4</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как вариант ещё могу предложить задать закругления первому и последнему элементу.

Comment: Ну это же дурной тон

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать как **oveflow:hidden** для родительского div(что по моему мнению лучше), так и **border-radius с определёнными углами** для первого и последнего дочернего элемента. Что именно выбрать, решать Вам.

```css
    #lkmenu {
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        border-radius: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .lbltab {
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
                  
    .lbltab:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .lbltab:last-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .lbltab:hover {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }
```

```html
    
        <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>тест</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="lkmenu">
                  <label class="lbltab">Пункт 1</label>
                  <label class="lbltab">Пункт 2</label>
                  <label class="lbltab">Пункт 3</label>
                  <label class="lbltab">Пункт 4</label>
                </div>
              </body>
    </html>
```